# trying to write a regex for a node replace script

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to replace this line

```
// app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
```

with this

```
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
```

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace which works but i cannot get it to work for the above because I cannot write the regex to recognize that line. Here is my attempt

```
var replace = require("replace");

replace({
    regex: "// app\.use\('/api',require\('\./api/api'\)\);", // string to be replaced
    replacement: "app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));", // replacement string
    paths: ['dist/server.js'], // path/to/your/file'
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
});
```

How do i rewrite the regex above to match `// app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));`

## DEMO

https://repl.it/repls/ChocolateLavenderBsddaemon

Comment: hmm `regex: "\/\/ app.use('\/api',require('.\/api\/api'));"` did not work.

Comment: this does not work `regex: "\/\/\sapp.use\('\/api',require\('\.\/api\/api'\)\);", // string to be replaced`

Comment: yes. but i have to recognize that specific line out of 10,000 lines

Comment: could you try this one ? `\/\/\s*app\.use\(["']\/api["']\s*,\s*require[^;]+;`

Comment: there is a syntax error with that. I dont know what it is cause i dont know regex that well

Comment: demo: https://repl.it/repls/ChocolateLavenderBsddaemon

Answer (score 1):

You just need proper escaping.

```
\/\/\s*app\.use\('\/api',require\('\.\/api\/api'\)\);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kHCdst/2/)

Comment: :( it doesnt work. I cant figure it out. Let me try to get a working example.

Comment: @Omar to the specified example it is working. can you add bit more data in you example ?

Comment: i just plugged in ur regex to my original question and it does not work

Comment: not saying u are wrong just saying it does not work in the replace plugin. so i am working on sharing an example

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping regex special symbols. Try this one.

```
\/\/\sapp.use\('\/api',require\('\.\/api\/api'\)\);
```

Comment: that doesnt work either. on a smaller test, `/api\/api` works. but not the whole line